# Route different paths to different services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have two services:

```
order             LoadBalancer   10.43.246.181   172.20.0.2    50001:31493/TCP                  11h
payment           LoadBalancer   10.43.150.222   172.20.0.2    50002:30885/TCP                  11h
```

which routes to different pods of containers with no context path and port 8080 exposed e.g. a.b.c.d:8080, v.x.y.z:8080

My Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-ing
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /order
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: order
                port:
                  number: 50001
          - path: /payment
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: payment
                port:
                  number: 50002
```

When I curl the `/order` path

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/order/orders
```

the pod `order` says

```
No mapping for POST /order/orders
```

---

I tried this

```
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: order
                port:
                  number: 50001
```

and curled

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/orders'
```

it works

---

My question: Is there a way to not forward the path "/order" to the pod? **How can I route different paths to different services like the first ingress manifest**? I've searched through SO but no one does this. Most of them route the nested paths to different services.

Comment: I think you are trying to achieve this [scenario](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout) , can you try using the example in the doc. Try creating ingress by removing path /order use only pathtype for order, keep the payment as it is.

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde I actually have more than 2 services. If I tried your way, I would face the same issue for "payment" and other services, wouldn't I? It means that the "payment" container, which doesn't have the contextPath "/payment", wouldn't match that rule's forwarded "/payment" path. The Simple Fanout section doesn't mention whether the containers have contextPath "/foo" and "/bar". I guess it will need it or there'll be the same issue of mine.

Comment: I think setting contextPath is the only way. This link also suggests to set "/app1" and "app2" https://www.stacksimplify.com/aws-eks/aws-alb-ingress/kubernetes-aws-alb-ingress-context-path-based-routing/#step-01-introduction.